# Как получить несколько частей строк и склеить их с помощью regex?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка:

```
8768 text text
text

868123
text
text
text.text

9875 text 
text

2353
text
text
```

И имеется такого рода запрос:

```
~(8768|9875|2353).*~iu
```

Тем не менее, я получаю только то, что есть на строке, но мне нужна вся информация, пока не встретится `\n\n` или конец всего текста. И ГЛАВНОЕ всё это потом склеить.

Comment: Может вам надо добавить флаг `s` и/или явно указать `\n\n` в выражении. И еще указать на чем вы работаете с регулярками. Ну и заодно более полно описать задачу, потому что ничего не понятно

Comment: Попробуйте [`preg_replace('~(8768|9875|2353).*(?:\R(?!\R).*)*~u', '', $str)`](https://ideone.com/sSkPFV), или [`preg_match_all('~(8768|9875|2353).*(?:\R(?!\R).*)*~iu', $str, $ms)`](https://ideone.com/9nAcQu). Пожалуйста, добавьте желаемый результат в вопрос.